# Mootools create input element

Tags: input, mootools

Hi i'am  using mootools and want to add an input lement

```
var newinput = new Element('input', {type: 'text', name: "removeusers", value:'hoho' });
$$(imgElement).getParent().adopt(newinput);
```

but the value isn't set

it creates only an empty element

```
<input type="text" name="removeusers">
```

and the displayed textfield is blank

Comment: one thing. don't use `$$(imgElement)` - it does a collection (think `document.querySelectorAll`), which in turn calls `.getParent()` on each and you end up with `[parentNode].adopt(input)`. use `$(imgElement)` or just `imgElement.getParent()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok everything was right with mootools, just called this code in an onclick listener which although calls this code:

```
elements.each( function( element ) { element.clearValue(); } );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working correctly. The value property is set in the DOM form object but is not displayed as an attribute of the input element. To do so would imply that the value was the defaultValue of the text field when the page was loaded. If you query the value it will return correctly:

```
console.log( $E('input[name=removeusers]').value );
> "hoho"
```

You can set the value attribute separately if needed with:

```
$E('input[name=removeusers]').setAttribute('value', 'hoho');
```